# PHP Includes and Meta Tags

Tags: php, meta

I know that in php you must define a variable before you are able to use the value in an echo statement. Is there a way around this? I'm using an include file for the website header, but I'd like to be able to define the meta tags on the individual pages. I'm not super php savvy.

Comment: How are you going to echo a variable that doesn't have a value yet??

Comment: You can either implement your own [2-step view](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/twoStepView.html)[Decorator or you could use a template engine like [`Twig`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/) which does this for you, and lets you pass values up from an inner template to an outer one. The key is you need to process your "page" before you process your layout so that the "page" can set values in the "layout".

Comment: if your not in the same scope as the current file, you can get the last defined value by using the global keyword like 
`global $variable; echo $variable;`... [http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

Comment: you don't HAVE to define it, but you should. most modern php installs will spit out warnings for using undefined vars.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are trying to do is this:

page1.php, you set the variables here and include your header:

```
<?php
    $myvar = "foo";
    include "header.php";
?>
```

header.php, you echo them out:

```
<?php
    echo $myvar;
?>
```